# pandas split function gives duplicated series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the Titanic dataset, and I want to extract title from people's names using `pandas.str.split` function.

```
>>> data.Title = data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1)
>>> data.Title
```

which result in the following, look just fine:

```
0           Mr
1          Mrs
2         Miss
3          Mrs
4           Mr
5           Mr
6           Mr
7       Master
8          Mrs
...
Name: Name, Length: 1309, dtype: object
```

it seems like each row has only on string which is `Mr` or `Mrs` or anything else. But if I index only one row, it shows this

```
>>> data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1)[0]
0     Mr
0     Mr
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

which I have no idea why is this happening, and I can't filter dataframe either:

```
data.Title == 'Mr'
0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
5      False
6      False
7      False
8      False
...
```

Comment: What return `data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1).sort_index().head()` ? Because it seems there is duplicated index

Comment: and for second issue what is `data.Title.head().tolist()` ? Maybe some trailing whitespaces.

Comment: `data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1).sort_index().head()` gives
`0       Mr
0       Mr
1      Mrs
1      Mrs
2     Miss
Name: Name, dtype: object`

Comment: and `data.Title.head().tolist()` gives
`[' Mr', ' Mrs', ' Miss', ' Mrs', ' Mr']`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1)[0]
```

means select all rows with `index == 0`. If duplicated indices get more rows.

So is necessary create unique index:

```
 data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

For second problem there are traling whitespaces, so is necessary remove them by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
data.Title = data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1).str.strip()
```

All together:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
data.Title = data.Name.str.split('[,.]').str.get(1).str.strip()
```